# Is there a way in which "space" of random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ is canonically a coaugmented coalgebra?

Tags: pr.probability, coalgebras

Consider the "space" of random variables with finite expectation on $\mathbb{R}$ in the following sense: we fix the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and put random variables in correspondence with equivalence classes of probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$, with addition being defined as convolution, and we define multiplication by scalars as pullback of measures by the "multiplication by a constant" map, with appropriate rescaling to conserve the total measure. This is, of course, not a linear space and not even an $\mathbb{R}$- or $\mathbb{Z}$-module, because $X + (-1 \cdot X) \ne 0$ and $2X \ne X + X$. However, let us ignore this for a moment.
$\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}$

Remember that a coalgebra $C$ is a linear space or a module over commutative unital ring $R$ with two linear operators, comultiplication $\Delta: C \to C \otimes C$ and counit $\varepsilon: C \to R$, satisfying coassociativity and counit property:
$$(\Delta \otimes \id)\circ \Delta = (\id \otimes \Delta) \circ \Delta$$
$$\beta_{r}\circ (\id \otimes \varepsilon) \circ \Delta = \beta_{l} \circ (\varepsilon \otimes \id)  \circ \Delta = \id$$
where $\beta_{r}$ and $\beta_{l}$ are canonical isomorphisms $C \otimes R \cong R \otimes C \cong C$.

Remember also that a coaugmented coalgebra is a coalgebra with coaugmentation map $u: R \to C$ such that $\varepsilon \circ u=\id$. There is a theorem about coaugmented coalgebras, saying that, (at least when these are coalgebras over a field $\mathbb{K}$), $\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{im}}$

$$C = \ker \varepsilon \oplus \im \ u$$

and

$$\forall x \in \ker \varepsilon: \Delta x = 1_{C} \otimes x + x \otimes 1_{C} + \sum_{x',x'' \in \ker \varepsilon}x' \otimes x''$$

where $1_{C}$ denotes $u(1_{R})$.

The expectation operator $\mathbb{E}$ is linear with respect to addition and multiplication by constant defined above. Put $\mathbb{E}$ in correspondence with $\varepsilon$, and define $$u: r \to \delta_{r}$$, where $\delta_{r}$ denotes constant random variable with unique value $r$ (having Dirac $\delta(x-r)$ probability distribution), and for random variable $\bar{X}$ with zero expectation define

$$\Delta: \Delta X = \delta_{1} \otimes X + X \otimes \delta_{1}$$.

For constant random variable $\delta_{1}$ define

$$\Delta \delta_{1} = \delta_{1} \otimes \delta_{1}$$

$u$ is "linear" in the sense that $u(\alpha r)= \alpha u(r)$, $u(r_{1}+r_{2})=\delta_{r_{1}} + \delta_{r_{2}}$,  and satisfies $\mathbb{E}[\delta_{1}]=1$.

We suppose the properties of $\otimes$ (whatever it is) are such that $\Delta$ is "linear" in the same sense, i.e.$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$

$$\Delta (X+Y)= \delta_{1}\otimes (X+Y)+(X+Y) \otimes \delta_{1}=\delta_{1}\otimes X + \delta_{1} \otimes Y + X \otimes \delta_{1} + Y \otimes \delta_{1} $$

$$\Delta (\alpha X) = \alpha \Delta X = \alpha (\delta_{1}\otimes X + X \otimes \delta_{1})$$

Then we notice that the axioms of coalgebra are satisfied (given our "tensor product" is associative, and tensor product of operators acts as we expect, of course), if we note that every random variable with finite expectation on $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely represented as $X = \bar{X} + \E[X]\delta_{1}$.  Then
$$\Delta X = \Delta (\bar{X} + \E[X]\delta_{1})= \delta_{1} \otimes \bar{X} + \bar{X} \otimes \delta_{1} + \E[X] \delta_{1} \otimes \delta_{1}$$
and one readily checks that coalgebra diagrams are satisfied. Moreover, the set of probability measures $\delta_{r}$ forms a one-dimensional linear space with respect to addition of random variables and "multiplication" by real constants, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and this space is exactly the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under the action of $u$. At the other hand, random variables with zero expectation are exactly the kernel of $\E$, and, since we are talking about random variables with finite expectation, the "space" of all such variables can be decomposed into
$$C = \ker \E \oplus \im \ u$$
with $\Delta$ of any element $\bar{X}$ of $\ker \E$ being $1_{C} \otimes \bar{X} + \bar{X} \otimes 1_{C}$, $1_{C}=\delta_{1}$.

So, at one hand, the space of random variables with finite expectation is not a coaugmented coalgebra by the book definition, since it is not a linear space and not even a module. At the other hand, it looks very much like one. So, my question is, in what sense, if in any, it is a coaugmented coalgebra with operations defined above?

Comment: In some fields of math, we define "coalgebra" more broadly (e.g., coalgebra over a cooperad), and then the coalgebras over R that you mentioned are a special case. Might be worth checking out: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comonoid. All you need is a monoidal category, an object $C$, the morphisms $\epsilon$ and $\Delta$, and some diagrams commuting. Does that notion help you?

Comment: It is a good starting point, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted, but I upvoted to bring it back to zero. Clearly a lot of thought went into writing the question.